# Verb tenses and concision needed

Tags: grammar, punctuation, tenses, concision

Can I say this in one whole sentence?

He is a Master of his trade but what makes him exceptional is that he ‘goes the extra mile’ gaining your trust, leaving you reassured of the problem solved

It’s long winded, the verb tenses are wrong and needs punctuation
It needs to be short and concise

This sentence is at the end of an appraisal, it’s central to the review

Can you help me?

Comment: *As a master of his trade, he is exceptional in going the extra mile to earn trust*. And why does the sentence need to be short for an appraisal?

Comment: You are seeking proofreading. That is off-topic, I'm afraid.